# TypeScript compiler incorrectly reports that action.payload does not exist

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm using Ngrx 4.03 and typeScript 2.5.2.

I have defined an action as such:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { IUser } from '../models';

export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = '[Auth] Login Success';
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = '[Auth] Logout Success';

export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGIN_SUCCESS;

  constructor (
    public payload: IUser
  ) {}
}

export class LogoutSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGOUT_SUCCESS;
}

export type AuthActions
 = LoginSuccess
 | LogoutSuccess;
```

In my corresponding reducer, TypeScript is telling me that `action.payload` does not exist on `Action`, even though I can log the value just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i would show the reducer if that is where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly sure that if you have one action (or more) without a payload, it will introduce this behavior.

So change this code:

```
export class LogoutSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGOUT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To

```
export class LogoutSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGOUT_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: null)
}
```

Comment: can you try with only: `constructor() {}` and let me know

Comment: sure. Am slammed at the moment on a different project, but should be able to get back to this sometime today.

Comment: Any fix for that yet?

Answer (score 0):

So in store's version of 4, the support for the payload in actions is removed as you can see an issue has already been reported. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/31

You can eliminate this by rewriting your actions like this.

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
export interface CustomAction extends Action {
  payload: any;
  appraisal_id: any;
}
```